# colorbox Jquery plugin, trying to open second popup

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm usinc colorbox to open popup #1:

```
<li class="getquotebtn"><a href="<?php bloginfo ('template_directory'); ?>/get-quote.php?productID=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">Get Quote</a></li>
```

and jquery:

```
$('.getquotebtn a').colorbox();
```

This works fine. But I've another button inside the content of get-quite.php that I'd like to open another popup...

```
<form name="getquotedata" action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="nameandsurname" id="popupnamefield" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'<?php _e('Name and Surname','medishop'); ?>':this.value;" onfocus="this.select()" onclick="if (this.value=='<?php _e('Name and Surname','medishop'); ?>'){this.value='';}" value="<?php _e('Name and Surname','medishop'); ?>">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="popupemailfield" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'youremail@domain.com':this.value;" onfocus="this.select()" onclick="if (this.value=='youremail@domain.com'){this.value='';}" value="youremail@domain.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="prod_ID" value="<?php echo $productID_from_url; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="prod_name" value="<?php echo get_the_title($productID_from_url); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="prod_url" value="<?php echo get_permalink($productID_from_url); ?>">
            <input type="submit" value="Get Quote" id="popupsbmt" onclick="$.colorbox({href:'<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/get-quote-sendmail.php'}); return false;">
    </form>
```

This is where the problems start!

I get error: `This content failed to load.`

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Let me see if I understood this correctly, you want to open a colorbox inside a colorbox?

Comment: @Trufa Yes, or simply open another colorbox and close previous one.

Comment: I think that the later is easier, I'm a little confused about your particular situation, would if help if I made you an example situation that isn't exactly like your code? Otherwise I would need more explanation as to what is you are doing...

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to work fine when you put a colorbox inside another, see [live example here](http://jsfiddle.net/JFdsX/1/).

```
<a class='inline' href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a>
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
        <a class='inline2' href="#inline_content2">open second</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div style='display:none'>
    <div id='inline_content2' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>hi second</div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
$(".inline2").colorbox({inline:true, width:"50%"});
```

Comment: I'm loading content from separate files. Both pop-ups are php files.could this be a problem?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze does the first colobox calll the form you are showing? If so, is the submit supposed to bring up the second one? If so what is the new content you are trying to bring?

Comment: First color box calls get-quote.php that contains the form. Submit is subbosted to bring up second colorbox correct. New pop-up is simply a php script that grabs variables from POST and puts them into wp_mail function. Also does checks and displays alerts. Like mail successfully sent etc.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze are you working locally or can you link me to a live example?

Comment: locally unfortunately... I cannot put it on jsfiddle :(